# Thunderbird autofill: also look for domain names

Tags: thunderbird

In the past, I could compose an e-mail in Thunderbird, and in the TO field write

"icecream"

and then my contact john@the **icecream** factory.com - to given an example - would show up.

Not anymore. TB only looks for names and the first part of e-mail addresses. Any idea what can be done?

Using Ubuntu 10.10, TB 3.1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this. Thunderbird's autocompletion can only match the beginning of each field of the contacts in your address book.

A [bug has been reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=558931) and [there are plans for improvement](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/auto_complete_of_addresses_with_substring#reply_3323651), but no solution has yet been released.

Note that there are some cases in which it may *look* like Thunderbird is performing substring matching, when really it is still just matching the beginning of other fields. For example, if you had the following contact in your address book,

> **Email:** john@theicecreamfactory.com
>   **Work Organization:** Icecream Factory

typing `icecream` in the To field would autocomplete to `john@theicecreamfactory.com`, but only because it matches the beginning of `Icecream Factory`. This behavior may be what you remember seeing in the past.

Comment: Thanks, too bad there is no solution. Will upvote the bug...